# Combinatorial analysis for option product payoffs

Tags: python, math, statistics, finance

I am struggling with this problem:

There are three types of options.

- ###### Vanilla Options

  - **Vanilla** options don´t change state from issue date to expiry date, in other words if any given individual has traded a vanilla option, it will stay active through its entire lifespan.
- ###### Knock In (Barrier Option)

  - **Knock In** options have all the attributes of a vanilla option but also have a barrier strike, that is responsible for activating it. A **Ki** option´s inicial state is *inactive* and if the underlying asset price reaches the barrier strike price the state is switched to *active* through it´s remaining lifespan, behaving like a vanilla option.
- ###### Knock Out (Barrier Option)

  - **Knock Out** options are similar to their Knock In sibling, the only difference being that it´s initial state is *active*. If the underlying asset price reaches the barrier strike price the state is switched to *inactive*, producing no effects during it´s remaining lifespan.

###### Some Rules

1. **Each individual barrier option can have only 1 barrier strike, which allows it to change state only once.**
2. **The barrier strike´s value can be above or below the initial underlying asset price, in other words the barrier can "look" up or down.**

   1. *Consider the initial underlying asset price as 20.00 (spot_price = 20.0).*
   2. *If the barrier strike is initialy set to 18.00 (bar_strike = 18.00) than the option changes state if the market price goes down to 18.00.*
   3. *If the barrier strike is initialy set to 22.00 (bar_strike = 22.00) than the option changes state if the market price goes up to 22.00.*
      3.**We are able to build financial products that contain multiple options inside it.**

*Let´s create an example for each of the option types. In these initial examples the financial product will contain only **one** option.*

###### Vanilla Option Example

**An individual buys a product that contains only one vanilla option.**
No matter what happens with the underlying price, there is only **1** possible state during the product´s lifespan.

###### Knock In Example

**An individual buys a product that contains only one Ki option.**
Now the product has **2** possible states. Inactive in the begining and possibly active if the barrier strike is touched by the underlying price.

###### Knock Out Example

**An individual buys a product that contains only one Ko option**
The product has only **1** state since it contains only one Ko option, if the barrier strike is triggered during its lifespan, we can assume that it will not produce any aditional results, so there is no need to continue monitoring it´s state.

###### Constraints

1. For a given product containing more than one barrier option. If two or more options have the same barrier strike prince, than the same event that triggers one of the barriers will trigger the other(s), so the number of possible states should be:

```py
max(option.qtty_states, other_option.qtty_states)
```

2. **Path dependency** of triggers greater than or less than the initial underlying price. Given a product with four options with different barrier strikes where:

```py
initial_underlying_price = 20.00
first_barrier = 18.00
second_barrier = 19.00
third_barrier = 21.00
fourth_barrier = 22.00
```

If the market goes down the second_barrier is triggered before the first_barrier and if the market price goes up to 23.00 the third_barrier is activated before the fourth_barrier.
There is no possible way that the first_barrier is triggered without the second_barrier being triggered before.

##### Possible States

*Here are the possible states of the example above containing 4 barrier options.*

| first_barrier | second_barrier | third_barrier | fourth_barrier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *initial state* | *initial state* | *initial state* | *initial state* |
| *initial state* | **triggered state** | *initial state* | *initial state* |
| *initial state* | *initial state* | **triggered state** | *initial state* |
| **triggered state** | **triggered state** | *initial state* | *initial state* |
| *initial state* | **triggered state** | **triggered state** | *initial state* |
| *initial state* | *initial state* | **triggered state** | **triggered state** |
| **triggered state** | **triggered state** | **triggered state** | *initial state* |
| *initial state* | **triggered state** | **triggered state** | **triggered state** |
| **triggered state** | **triggered state** | **triggered state** | **triggered state** |

### The Problem

Given a composition of one or more options, with one or more types (vanilla, ki or ko), where the barriers can be the same or different between each other. I am trying to think of a method that calculate the quantity of different states and therefore the different payoff graphs that explain the product.

Comment: Why would you think that it might not  be possible to calculate this? Are you supposed to make some kind of proof that a certain calculation is possible or not?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If a product only switches state once, then this is pretty easy.  Count how many unique trigger points there are.  The number of states is that number plus 1.